# Two arrays in a custom object

Tags: arrays, powershell, pscustomobject

I'm trying to create a table with two arrays and I'm not sure whats the best way to make this happen.  Here is my code

```
$nomatchsam += $enabled.SamAccountName
$nomatch10 += $enabled.extensionAttribute10
```

I'd like to take these arrays and do something like this

```
% $nomatchsam |New-Object PSObject -Property @{

SamAccountName = $_;
extensionAttribute10 = $nomatch1
}
```

This is not working anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong so far as I know. It should be something more like:

```
$NewObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    SamAccountName = $nomatchsam
    extensionAttribute10 = $nomatch1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1..1000 | %{$NewObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    SamAccountName = $enabled.SamAccountName
    extensionAttribute10 = $enabled.extensionAttribute10
}}
$NewObject
```

Comment: the `1..1000 | %{}` loop is pointless. You just created the exact same object 1000 times.

Comment: how else can I iterate through?  Your code didn't iterate.

Comment: You have your arrays already existing. You don't need to iterate. Yours doesn't iterate either, it quite literally performs the exact same action 1000 times.

Comment: 1..(($enabled.SamAccountName).count) worked, I cannot get your code to work but mine is working fine.  I had to remove the arrays and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1..1000 | %{} is on the right lines, with some modification. 1000 objects do get created here so have the correct upper limit. Also use the index, as I believe you intended to show. This works:

```
0..($nomatchsam.count - 1) | % {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        'SamAccountName'       = $nomatchsam[$_]
        'ExtensionAttribute10' = $nomatch10[$_]
    }
}
```